# How to design UI controls like these?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmYeR.png]

How are these controls(in the left) made/designed, are these just tableview with text is arranged top and bottom or some labels that imitate textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done relatively easily with a [view-based NSTableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/ViewBasedTables/ViewBasedTables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH15-SW2). It's impossible to tell from a screenshot how the app in question is *actually* implemented, but that would be my approach if I were starting from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Andrew Madsen's answer, the gray background that's shown when a row is clicked is probably drawn in a subclass of `NSTableRowView`, using `- (void)drawSelectionInRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect`.